# Codeigniter - <textarea></textarea> POST alterate content

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I have some problem with posting data in codeigniter.
I want to make an editor for .php files and when i want to post a string like this

`<?php echo $my_var; ?><p>sample text</p>`

the obtained result in

`$_POST['element_name']`

is

`<!--<?php echo $my_var; ?>--><p>sample text</p>`

Why happen this? How i can obtain the original text?

Here is part of my code

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="">
    <textarea id="editor_original"><?php echo $editor_original;?></textarea>
    <textarea name="editor" id="editor"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('editor_original'), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"},
        keyMap: "sublime",
        autoCloseBrackets: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        mode: "application/x-httpd-php",
        showCursorWhenSelecting: true,
        theme: "monokai",
        onBlur: function () { 
             editor.save();             
        }

      });
   $("#editor").val(editor.getValue());
```

**PHP**

```
$data = $this->page_m->array_from_post(array('editor'));
echo $data; // here output is <!--<?php echo $my_var; ?>--><p>sample text</p>


public function array_from_post($fields)
{
    $data = array();
    foreach($fields as $field)
    {
        $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: What? First of all, how are you posting that string? Can you provide more code? Specifically the code in your controller.

Comment: the way to retrieve POST data in CI is `$this->input->post("editor")`, not like this:  `$data = $this->page_m->array_from_post(array('editor'));`

Comment: I know that, array_from_post is a personal function

Comment: @CodeGodie array_from_post is a custom function , part of page_m model, so , is correct the way used by @ Cezar Rahaian

Comment: I see that now, you need to be more specific with your question. I think the problem is your JS plugin. It is adding comments when its not supposed to correct? is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the right data, but, because of echo , the output is modified. 
Use `echo htmlentities($this->input->post('editor'));` to see the posted content.

If you want to save the content, use something like this:

```
write_file('out_file.php', stripslashes($this->input->post('editor')));
```

whre `write_file` is

```
function write_file($path, $data, $mode = FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE_DESTRUCTIVE)
    {
        if ( ! $fp = @fopen($path, $mode))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
        fwrite($fp, $data);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);

        return TRUE;
    }
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: i newer know this behavior. Thank you for all hint, all works fine now.